# Can't boot into windows if it's not the first HDD in boot order (Linux)

Tags: linux, boot, dual-boot, elementary-os

I installed eOS recently with a custom install (selected separate home, root, and swap partitions).

After the install, eOS boots perfectly. However when I try to choose the Windows 8 option it will not boot into it: it shows the Windows logo for a second then reboots my PC.

I managed to boot into Windows by going into the BIOS and changing the boot order of my HDD's (the windows is on a different HDD) and then windows boots immediately (no GRUB).

How can I get Windows to boot from GRUB?

EDIT:

This is my current config http://paste.ubuntu.com/6594815/ (Both entries of windows 8 there do the same thing).

After a few boot attempts into windows I get this message: [image]

Comment: what version of grub are you using?

Comment: @AlexejMagura not sure I can test when I get home but it shouldn't matter much if I get past the grub into the windows logo for a second should it?

Comment: @AlexejMagura I have grub '1.99-21ubuntu3.10' installed

Comment: some versions of Grub only support a particular type of partition table (Grub 2 requires GPT, I believe), which is not supported by the Windows OS.  Just thought that I'd check to see if that might be somehow related.

Comment: Is the signature of the boot-loader a solved problem in eOS?

Comment: @AlexejMagura, no, grub2 does not require gpt.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the Boot order in the BIOS helps, you might try to swap hd0 and hd1 before booting Win8.

Comment: If you look at the config I posted I use drivemap -s (hd0) (hd1) which is supposed to swap the drives

Comment: @Jason I did not see that in your config. This swap is probpably not going deep enough.